# Changing player position after changing scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to make a transitioning system similar to something like Castlevania, where scenes have multiple exits and entrances, although I'm having trouble changing the players position dependant on which entrance they use. I'm also trying to keep it all changeable on the fly with the one script.

TL:DR: Need help changing the position of the player when they transition.

```
 public class SceneTransition : MonoBehaviour {

    public string sceneTo;
    public Transform newPos;
    public Transform playerChar;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player") {

            SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneTo);
            playerChar.position = newPos.position;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the newposition in an object that is not destroyed between scene changes, or in a static variable. Then when you're on the new scene, apply the new position to the player.

Static variable approach:

```
static Vector3 playernewpos; //In some class, for example MyClass
```

Before Switching scenes:

```
MyClass.playernewpos = newPos.position;
```

After switching scenes:

```
playerChar.position = MyClass.playernewpos;
```

Comment: So essentially loading specific co-ords through empty gameObjects that are in every scene?

Comment: I would use the static variable approach, save the pos in a static Vector3 in some class, I have a class specific for this kind of static variables :P

Comment: Cheers! I've got this working now appreciate the help!